# Unterminated address regex using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a script in Perl running on Linux and I get an error unterminated address regex in the line below.

```
cat $filename | sed ‘sed /^\\s*$/d’ | wc -l
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to remove whitespace-only lines from your file.  The sed syntax is:

```
/^\s*$/d
```

What you're passing to sed is

```
sed /^\\s*$/d
```

This incidentally is a form of substitution s/find/replace/, but using `e` instead of the slash.  (You can use almost any character there.) 
Since there are no other `e`s to terminate the search and replacement patterns, sed throws an error.

What you need is:

```
% cat $filename | sed '/^\s*$/d' | wc -l
```

Or without cat:

```
% sed '/^\s*$/d' $filename | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `-E` regex option

```
sed -E '/^\s*$/d' $filename | wc -l
```